# message in notify.js not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show success message in the notify but it doesn't appear .
i included files in this way :

```
   <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/notify.min.js"></script>
```

the code is :

```
$(function(){
  $(".post-joya").on("click",function(){
    $.notify({
        title: 'Success',
        text: 'Success message',
        icon: "done"
    }, {
        //options 
        className: "success"
    });
});
```

[image]});

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you include the relevant CSS? How can you be sure that the click is triggered?

Comment: Also don't forget to include the jQuery files aswell.

Comment: pl share link!!

Comment: @ Jeremy Thille i didn't include any css for notify.js                                                           <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/notify.min.js"></script>

Comment: the click is triggered i'm sure , and there's not error in the console